# I need to select the value up to certain character

Tags: mysql

I have a field that could contain the following Value.

```
Hello.  This value is from my MySQL table.  ---End Message---  Timestamped 6:00pm
```

I want to grab everything before the `---End Message---` String.  It will always be formatted that way.  So basically I just want to grab `Hello.  This value is from my MySQL table.`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substring_index('Hello.  This value is from my MySQL table.  ---End Message','---End Message---',1)
```

Comment: This will blow up if you have a single "-" in the contents, hence the reason he's using such a substantial delimiter like "---End Message---".

Comment: @Nick Why not just use the full delimiter?

Comment: Great! What if there are multiple Delimiters?  it could happen.  Such as: `Hello.  This value is from my MySQL table.  ---End Message---  Timestamped 6:00pm  ---End Message---  Timestamped 5:00pm`.  Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: What do you want to extract in your last example? You can even use nested substring_index() functions.

Comment: I just want to extract `Hello. This value is from my MySQL table.`.  No matter how many times `---End Message---` appears, I want to grab everything before the first one.

Comment: In this case it works what I've already wrote you. Test yourself.